# Vega-lite: skip invalid values instead of treating as 0 for aggregate sum

Tags: vega-lite, vega

When doing an aggregate sum on a column and charting it using Vega-Lite, is it possible to skip invalid values instead of treating them as 0 when doing the addition? When there is missing/invalid data, I want to show it as such, rather than as 0.

For example, this [graph](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AHE2bMoLgByCAAIImNlADWlnJqhxLbUuss6EcSopUkTBRUUGIkQQY1NABtUGUguDQQACYABhSU-jSARn50gLJkpBwcUwgAgA9kgDkkGoCAT1r6kABfBXjE5PTM7LyCpSL0NnUkWTJopWr0HLSmnvmOrswk9F6s3PycwuTR8cmK6eSAZnmlZvQ6huXA1cW+rZSdoeSyMZwpkBmQABZzkCXVJLTp3NbAx4DFK7dAlMpfH7XBazEErcEbfr5aGvdDvEoI5JzZEgJFtAC6HRAmDGsggADNRghYqAoBEoAxBN10DgkOoIHAAGKCNhBAAUCUwDAQMTMlTMZIAlAEkBV0NVbqzBOzOfdubz+UKRZhxUEpTLGvKlUoVclmrckGR3nxdXEQGwcMkIFKAnSaHBBMpktVrarvu1Qe7Pd6lL7-YH0M0Q7b2mShuo2AwcExLjEwSAKaCGQHYmGLvmNWyOVyQJI2DRZKKYhKpZR7HBGqnLGYAPpmK0gG3ofmaaLkpRwWRQNjKevDUAzUCx4voCVJJSYRqfZKrBA4faCdqUzmNODqZkgCdTmcTNCgS6Lv3LkDhSJrqmb8EARwY4x0wR0pDhiAU7CmeoQgEu8YgMOfpHO+W7oLIbAIPWESHkoyDqPYyTCLISS3Je06zregIkZByQvlEAQbghIDfr+dBBDQgGUiBoxkY+UEwV8NHgkhKGyGhbSUph2HgbxyR7vWmDUUYgg6B64FTrIqwqckhHXkUwnkm0QA) is what I expect when aggregating on `date` to get the sums for `x` and `y`.
[image]

Whereas in this [example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AHE2bMoLgByCAAIImNlADWlnJqhxLbUuss6EcSopUkTBRUUGIkQQY1NABtUGUguDQQACYABhSU-jSARn50gLJkpBwcUwgAgA9kgDkkGoCAT1r6kABfBXjE5PTM7LyCpSL0NnUkWTJopWr0HLSmnvmOrswk9F6s3PycwuTR8cmK6eSAZnmlZvQ6huXA1cW+rZSdoeSyMZwpkBmQABZzkCXVJLTp3NbAx4DFK7dAlMpfH7XBZXVq3BL3dYZTZQmEgd4lBHJObIkBItoAXQ6IEwY1kEAAZqMELFQFAIlAGIJuugcEh1BA4AAxQRsIIACnRDAQMTMlTM5IAlAEkBV0NVbmzBByuRiQLz+UKReLJdKzI15UqlCrks1bkgyO8+Bi4iA2DhkhApQF6TQ4IJlMlqlbVd92qC3R6vUofX6A+hmsGbe1yUN1GwGDgmJcYmCQJTQYz-bFQxc8xr2ZzuSBJGwaLIxTETZR7HBGinLGYAPpmS0ga3oAWaaIUpRwWRQNjKOvDUAzUAxovodFJJSYRqfZKrBA4faCdpUrmNODqFkgMcTqcTNCgS7z32LkDhSIr6nr8EARwY4x0wR0pDDIATiKJ6hCAC5xiAg6+kcr4bugshsAgdYRPuSjIOo9jJMIshJLc56TtO16AkR4HJE+UQBGucEgJ+350EEND-lSQGjCR94QVBXxUeCCFIbIKFtFS6GYaB3HJDudaYJRRiCDo7qgROsirEpyT4ZeRSCRSbRAA), the `y` value for both rows where `date=2022-01-20` are NaN, so I would want there to be no data point for the sum of column `y` and show it as missing data, instead of as 0.
[image]

Is there a way to do that? I’ve looked through the documentation but may have missed something. I've tried using filter [like so](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AHE2bMoLgByCAAIImNlADWlnJqhxLbUuss6EcSopUkTBRUUGIkQQY1NABtUGUguDQQACYABhSU-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-uCACODDjDowQ6KQQYgLewrhkhRZviA-KaF836-ugshsAgS4RCBSjIOo9jJMIshJLc0F3g+8GTqEICvskaFRAEDE4XhsgEUENDEZSZGjKJkmnnRRyYYxIDMaxsjsW0lJcTx4lyckgFLpgslGE6WiibeinXnZ6BCbBRSmeSbRAA), but that filters out an entire row, rather than just the invalid value of a particular column for the row when doing the sum.

I’m thinking something like pandas [GroupBy.sum(min_coun=1)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), so that if there isn't at least 1 non-NaN value, then the result will be presented as NaN.

Answer (score 1):

OK, try this which removes NaN and null but leaves zero.

[Editor.](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AHE2bMoLgByCAAIImNlADWlnJqhxLbUuss6EcSopUkTBRUUGIkQQY1NABtUGUguDQQACYABhSU-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)

Or this which removes a load of useless transforms.

[Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289AHE2bMoLgByCAAIImNlADWlnJqhxLbUuss6EcSopUkTBRUUGIkQQY1NABtUGUguDQQACYABhSU-jSARn50gLJkpBwcUwgAgA9kgDkkGoCAT1r6kABfBXjE5PTM7LyCpSL0NnUkWTJopWr0HLSmnvmOrswk9F6s3PycwuTR8cmK6eSAZnmlZvQ6huXA1cW+rZSdoeSyMZwpkBmQABZzkCXVJLTp3NbAx4DFK7dAlMpfH7XBZXVq3BL3dYZTZQmEgd4lBHJObIkBItoAXQ6IEwY1kEAAZqMELFQFAIlAGIJuugcEh1BA4AAxQRsIIACnRDAQMTMlTM5IAlAEkBV0NVbmzBByuRiQLz+UKReLJdKzI15UqlCrks1bozBMpYt8FpTQfSaIJVuo0KB3XAHclwpEkkogzRHagaVE2rckGR3nwMXEQGwcMkIFKAn6A+gg1FlaqQHmkhShuo2AwcExLjEwQF7HBmpTyUo4LIoGxlDQJj7naEQNmI3WlJhGp9kqsEDh9oJ2lSuY04N7UMm2x2uz3+5dfTR-UPiwFR+P0ABHBjjHTBHSkdpKDsi5c7vfJBvNEdj8GyNgIbsROdKZB1HsZJhFkEtQTXTtu2GUBtwHXccyLCJ83fY8QDPC86CCGgbype9Rl7QcX0bQ8P2SL8f1kP8YwAvlgP7I9wWnbtMEPIxPS0XsO1kVYeOSSCNyKGMKTaIA)

```json
    {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
      "description": "Google's stock price over time.",
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"date": "2022-01-20", "g": "apples", "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN"},
          {"date": "2022-01-20", "g": "oranges", "x": "10", "y": "20"},
          {"date": "2022-01-21", "g": "oranges", "x": "30", "y": "NaN"},
          {"date": "2022-01-21", "g": "grapes", "x": "40", "y": "20"},
          {"date": "2022-01-22", "g": "apples", "x": "NaN", "y": "NaN"},
          {"date": "2022-01-22", "g": "grapes", "x": "10", "y": "NaN"}
        ]
      },
      "transform": [
        {"calculate": "parseFloat(datum['x'])", "as": "x"},
        {"calculate": "parseFloat(datum['y'])", "as": "y"},
        {"fold": ["x", "y"]},
        **{"filter": {"field": "value", "valid": true}},**
        {
          "aggregate": [{"op": "sum", "field": "value", "as": "value"}],
          "groupby": ["date", "key"]
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {"x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"}},
      "layer": [
        {
          "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal"}
          },
          "mark": "line"
        },
        {
          "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
            "color": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal"}
          },
          "mark": {"type": "point", "tooltip": {"content": "encoding"}}
        }
      ]
    }
```